# Twitter Bootstrap's Collapse functionality's header editing is hard

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, web2py

How to have following layout for expand/collapse functionality?

```
+ This is header having some text and links   
      This is item which was shown pressing + sign
      This is another item...
```

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) has functionality but I cannot edit that  [Collapsible Group Item #1](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapseOne) to be just '+' sign AND have **plain** text/links right after that.

Live http://jsfiddle.net/c4jMh/2/ where the problem is visible and same code also here:

```
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        +
      </a>
        This line should be next to above '+' sign and here some example link to be reside on that line also <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/">jsfiddle.net</a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use Bootstrap on web2py framework to that matter.

Comment: So, what HTML are you working with?

Comment: Without any HTML, any idea of the context, environment, or platform, this question is impossible to answer. Try to edit some more detail into the post.

Comment: @Chris I added snippet. Hopefully that now makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @DavidThomas HTML ( -5 I suppose) is now included, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I saw the notification earlier, while I was at work, and didn't have time to respond. I've voted to re-open though, since the HTML makes it answerable.

Comment: @DavidThomas No prob, voluntary stuff here :) What comes to my challenge  I suppose I should go for something like http://jasalguero.com/ledld/development/web/expandable-list/ unless editing Bootstrap's CSS (not preferable way?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also came with solution where there is no table formatting used [http://jsfiddle.net/c4jMh/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/vfLY5/2/)

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <div class="accordion-toggle group-accordion-toggle">
            <a href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion2" data-toggle="collapse" class=""><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
            <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/">jsfiddle.net</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">Anim pariatur cliche...</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">Anim pariatur cliche...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

​

```
$('.accordion').on('show hide', function(e) {
$(e.target).siblings('.accordion-heading').find('.accordion-toggle i').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus', 200);});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified accordion-heading to use table, so that it comes in a single row. Not sure if this is what you want.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
<div class="accordion-group">
<div class="accordion-heading">
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a></td>
    <td>  This line should be next to above '+' sign and here some example link to be reside on that line also<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/">jsfiddle.net</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>   
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
  <div class="accordion-inner">
    Anim pariatur cliche...
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
<div class="accordion-heading">
  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"   href="#collapseTwo">
    Collapsible Group Item #2
  </a>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
  <div class="accordion-inner">
    Anim pariatur cliche...
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry to respond until now @abdullah-shaikh, missed your reply. Yes your answer will do I tested it on http://jsfiddle.net/c4jMh/3/ thank you!